# Increase Number in the url

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to increase the number i in the URL, ten by ten, to be able to open several pages at the same time, but I get the following error. Can someone help me to correct the code?

```
1 i = 0

url = ("https://www.minsalud.gov.co/sites/rid/Paginas/freesearchresults.aspxk=&k=Salud%20Mental%20Legislacion#k=%2CSalud%20Mental%20Legislacion=+ 1"+ i+")")

for i in url():

    sum =("+10")

print (url)

**TypeError: must be str, not int**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to convert integers to strings using str() when joining ints with strings. Try something like this:

```
i = 0

first_part = "https://www.minsalud.gov.co/sites/rid/Paginas/freesearchresults.aspxk=&k=Salud%20Mental%20Legislacion#k=%2CSalud%20Mental%20Legislacion=+"
for j in range(0,10):
    i = i + 10
    url = (first_part + str(i) + ")")

    print (url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to just increase the value of `i` by `10` every time. You can use a builtin function like [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) in python. Do check it out, `range` is used quite often in conjunction with the `for` loop in python

```
for i in range(1 , 100, 10):
    url = "https://www.minsalud.gov.co/sites/rid/Paginas/freesearchresults.aspxk=&k=Salud%20Mental%20Legislacion#k=%2CSalud%20Mental%20Legislacion=+ "+ str(i)+")"
    print(url)
```

The above `for` loop will start with a value of `i = 1`, with an increment of `10` every time until `i` reaches a maximum value that is less than `100`. The value of `i` in the above for loop will be

```
1
11
21
31
41
51
61
71
81
91
```

When `i` becomes `101`, it ends the for loop.

Edit : To write these url's to a file

```
with open('urls.txt','w') as f:
    for i in range(1 , 100, 10):
        url = "https://www.minsalud.gov.co/sites/rid/Paginas/freesearchresults.aspxk=&k=Salud%20Mental%20Legislacion#k=%2CSalud%20Mental%20Legislacion=+ "+ str(i)+")"
        f.write(url+'\n')
```

For more information, checkout [reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in python3

Comment: Right now, i am trying to do a txt file. Can I create a txt with the URL info. Btw: Thanks a lot

Comment: Would you like all of the url's stored in a text file? @SebastiánRamírez

Comment: Yes, I have to make webscrapping for each url, so this is diserable :)

Comment: You can do that, but it's really just an extra effort to write them to a file and read them again. Better save these url's to a list and then read from that list. But, If you have to write them to a file, I can update my answer that reflects this scenario

Comment: Ohh, that´s a good idea, but at the end I know that my teacher will request the file.

Comment: well, I added it just in case for you @SebastiánRamírez. Let me know if that makes sense